# .net exception There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first

Tags: mysql, sql, .net

I am trying to save multiple rows of data using mysql transaction, but I get an error when i execute this code at the indicated line

```
Using conn As New MySqlConnection(connStr)
    conn.Open()

    Using sqlTrans As MySqlTransaction = conn.BeginTransaction()

        Try
            Dim bHasRows As Boolean
            dim sSql as string

            For Each kv As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In dicOpts
                If String.IsNullOrEmpty(kv.Key) Then Continue For
                String.format("Select * FROM Options WHERE name = '{0}';",kv.Key)
                Using cmd As New MySqlCommand(qb.GetQuery, conn)
                    bHasRows = cmd.ExecuteReader().HasRows
                End Using

                If bHasRows Then
                    ssql=String.format("UPDATE Options SET value ='{0}' WHERE name = '{1}';", kv.Value,kv.Key)
                Else
                    ssql=String.format("INSERT INTO Options(name,Value) values('{0}','{1}';",kv.Key, kv.Value)
                End If
                Using cmd As New MySqlCommand(qb.GetQuery, conn)
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()    // <----- This is the error line
                End Using
            Next

        sqlTrans.Commit()
    Catch ex As Exception
        sqlTrans.Rollback()
        Throw
    Finally

    End Try
End Using
```

The error i am getting

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection
>   which must be closed first

As you can see, the reader is closed with every using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is where you step wrong:

```
bHasRows = cmd.ExecuteReader().HasRows
```

use `Using` on the datareader:

```
Using dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    bHasRows = dr.HasRows
End Using
```

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what the message reads. `bHasRows = cmd.ExecuteReader().HasRows` opens DataReader and doesn't close. Correct form is

```
Using cmd As New MySqlCommand(qb.GetQuery, conn)
    Dim r = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    bHasRows = r.HasRows
    r.Close()
End Using
```